# How we use LTBouncytextfield library in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I am new on  **Stack overflow**. Can you tell me how to use [`LTBouncyTextField`](https://github.com/lexrus/LTBouncyPlaceholder) library for animating the right placeholder of the text field.

My code is

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var registrationView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var Username: LTBouncyTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Email: LTBouncyTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Password: LTBouncyTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var ConformPass: LTBouncyTextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    registrationView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    registrationView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    Username.abbreviatedPlaceholder = " username"
    Username.alwaysBouncePlaceholder = true
    Email.abbreviatedPlaceholder = "email"
    Email.alwaysBouncePlaceholder = true
    Password.abbreviatedPlaceholder = "password"
    Password.alwaysBouncePlaceholder = true
    ConformPass.abbreviatedPlaceholder = "confirmpass"
    ConformPass.alwaysBouncePlaceholder = true
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple. Just drag and drop the `UITextField+LTBouncyPlaceholder.swift` into your project. Select it as the class of `textField`. Add attributes and it should work.

[image]